# How to test a real ECU via CANoe

Tags: vector, ethernet, diagnostics, canoe

I am new with CANoe, and now I am trying to test a real ECU by sending diagnostic requests to it and get response from the ECU via CANoe. I use VN5610A and CANoe software is CANoe.Ethernet. I connected the VN5610A to PC and the ECU. I configured the Diagnostics/ISO TP configuration by uploading a ODX file as database. Then when i start logging, I can see the ethernet package infomation in the trace window. And if i send request via other external tools, i can also see the communication in the trace window. But how can i send request via Caone?

I now have some questions firstly:

1. I want to test a real ECU, should I use the simulation setup? I mean should i need to simulate the real ECU as a simuLated ECU? If not, I would not use Diagnostics Console to send request. Actually I tried to setup the simulated ECU and send request via Diagnostics Console. But the real ECU did not really received the request, just the simuated ECU received.
2. in the Vector Hardware Config, we can define VN5610A's IP address, should this IP address the same as my PC IP address? If not the same? which IP address should be assigned to "Tester Present"?
3. If config below in the Vector Hardware Config correct?  Should PC and CANoe be the same virtual Port?

[image]

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to simulate real ECUs, the best way normally is to generate a rest bus simulation for the whole bus using the respective signal data bases and then comment out the ECU you need and connect it to the interface, instead. ECUs that are deactivated in the simulation setup are not simulated and thus can be set to the real bus. When the ECU is activated, you should also see the connection change in the simulation setup to the other wire. If you do not deactivate the ECU, CANoe will simulate it for you.

Maybe you can also have a look at the Examples. If you have not installed them together with CANoe, I recommend doing so. They're actually quite good :-)

Comment: Hi @MaPr, Thank you for the reply. I am not really understand the rest bus simulation. I now just have data base relating to the target ECU. So in the rest bus simulation, i can just simulate the target ECU. Do you mean if I deactivate the simulated target ECU when I start logging, then the signal should be set to the real ECU?

Comment: By the way, would you recommend some examples regarding my case? I can just find examples for sending requests to simulated ECUs. Thanks.